# JSON parse object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON string which comes from a HTTP request:

```
{ '{firstname:\'Joe\'}': '' } // output of console.log(req.body);
```

I have tried to print the value to console using:

```
console.log(req.body.firstname);
```

but it says the value is undefined. How can I get the value of firstname?

To see what the client is doing this is how it sends the JSON request:

```
//angular2
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        this.http.post(
            'http://192.168.1.45:3000/test', 
            JSON.stringify({firstname:'Joe'}), //This is the parameter I want
            {headers:headers}
        )
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a validate JSON

Comment: `{firstname:\'Joe\'}` is `key` of the object..

Comment: You shown object is either already parsed into a JavaScript Object or it is an invalid JSON String. Beside that the part before the `:` is the key (So your key is `{firstname:\'Joe\'}`). It indicates that either the response is already wrong or you are doing something wrong in between.

Comment: Can you please send complete Json response

Comment: I am not sure why the downvote?

Comment: @VasimVanzara There is no response, just the request. The client is sending the request to the server and it is printing it on the server side. No response is sent back.

Comment: I didn't down-vote but the reason for the down-vote most likely is, because if you have basic knowledge in javascript then you should know that the object`{ '{firstname:\'Joe\'}': '' }`  has the key `{firstname:\'Joe\'}`  and an empty string as values. So the object does not have any key `firstname` thats why you get `undefined` as result. Your initial question should have been, why you get this malformed `{ '{firstname:\'Joe\'}': '' }`.

Answer (score 0):

converts an array to a JSON string by using JSON.stringify, and then converts the string back to an array by using JSON.parse

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function gettz(){
     var str=JSON.stringify({firstname:'Joe'});
     console.log(str);
     //Parse an object 
     dataObj = JSON.parse(str);
    // get object property
      console.log(dataObj.firstname);
    }

    </script>
    </head>
     <body>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="PrintJson" onclick="gettz();">
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Why should the OP create a JSON String out of an JavaScript Object, just to convert it back to an JavaScript Object in the next line? Why not just write `dataObj = '{firstname:'Joe'}';` ?

Comment: If @user2924127 wants to access object property using parse json. Similar to OOP concept.

Comment: When you sent it in header its already in string format you need to parse it.After you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive it you need to parse the response first because its coming as a string, so do:

```
var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(req.body);
console.log(parsedResponse.firstname); //Now you can access the object
```

Comment: If `{ '{firstname:\'Joe\'}': '' } `  is really the output of `console.log(req.body);` then `JSON.parse` of that would result in `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '`, because for JSON the keys must be quoted with double quotes.